# Transfer money from crypto account to normal bank account

Tags: transactions, fraud, banks

I'm totally unknown about this topic so I come to all of you with my question.

I sold something online and the buyer wants to pay me through his cryptoaccount. But then he told me that there is an issue with his account and that he needs me to buy a Steam gift card of 50 euro. When I buy this I will receive an e-code that he needs to convert crypto into money?

Is this all legit or is this a total scam?

Comment: I think this is scam Bitcoin and other crypto derived to it, not work with the Stream gift card

Answer (score 1):

You cannot transfer money from crypto to banks directly. You would have to sell the crypto currencies on a special marketplace for cryptos, after that you can get them paid out to your bank account. But you will have varying exchange rates depending on which amount you will sell and what the actual market price is at the time you sell it. Plus additional transaction costs.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this all legit or is this a total scam?

You should assume it is a scam and stop wasting time with this person.

If they have cryptocurrency, they know how to convert it into whatever currency (e.g. dollars) and payment method (e.g. cash in hand, bank transfer, ...) you find acceptable.

Any messing around with currencies or payment methods you are unfamiliar with is almost certainly a ruse to get you confused into making an expensive mistake or series of mistakes.

> I'm totally unknown about this topic

That's probably what the other person is trying to exploit.